# What is the verbal phrase for "making a candle stop burning"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

> **[blow](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/blow_1?q=blow)** [intransitive, transitive] to be moved by the wind, somebody’s
> breath, etc.; to move something in this way
>
> - adv./prep. *My hat blew off*.
> - adj. *The door blew open*.
>
> **blow somebody/something + adv./prep**.
> *I was almost blown over by the wind.*
> *She blew the dust off the book*.
> *The ship was blown onto the rocks*.
> *The bomb blast blew two passers-by across the street.*
>
> **blow something + adj.**
> *The wind blew the door shut*.

---

I want to use the structure "**blow something + preposition**" with "*the candles*", but I don't know the preposition that express "**to make a fire stop burning**".

> 1. **[off](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/off_2)** (*preposition*) down or away from a place or at a distance in space or time
>
> - *I fell **off** the ladder*.
> - *Keep **off** the grass!*
>
> 2. used to say that something has been removed
>
> - You need to take the top **off** the bottle first!
> - I want about an inch **off** the back of my hair.
>
> 3. away from work or duty
>
> - *He's had ten days **off** school.*

"**off**" is a preposition, but the dictionary doesn't say anything about fire, I also think about the adjective "**extinguished**", but it sounds bizarre.

Can we say "**to blow the candles off**" or "**extinguished**"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Extinguish* is the verb that means *to cause a fire or light to cease to burn or shine*.

> The fire brigade extinguished the fire.

"Put out" is a more casual, and possibly wider-used way of saying the same thing.

> I put out the fire.

These can refer to almost any method of extinguishing a fire, such as smothering it, using water, or a fire-extinguisher.

"Blow **out**" is the idiomatic way of stating that a fire has extinguished by a sudden gust of air. This is most commonly used when people blow out a candle with their own breath, but it can also happen to a fire in a fireplace if a gust of wind suddenly comes down the chimney. It would be very unusual for this to happen to a large fire.

> He blew out the candles on his birthday cake.

Comment: So much better answer than mine, it makes me want to delete it. hahaha

Answer (score 4):

Do you really have/want/need to go with the verb *to blow*? A good way to say is

> [to put out](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/put-out-something): to stop something that is burning from continuing to burn.
>   *Be sure **to put out** your campfire before you go to sleep.*

Still, if you must use *to blow*, you'd have to say *to blow the candles **out***, not **off**.

Comment: No - with **blow** it's [**out**, not **off**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blow+the+candles+off%2Cblow+the+candles+out&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblow%20the%20candles%20out%3B%2Cc0) (also *blow **out** the candles*, never *blow **off** the candles*).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica You're right, just did the research. Thanks!

Comment: No it isn't - it's _blow out_, the same as _put out_. A fire has _gone out_ when it has used up all its fuel and stopped burning.

Comment: @KateBunting just corrected the answer. Thanks!